# Program to Play Snake

Tags: facebook

I recently started playing the facebook game snake. If you have never tried it, you move a small snake around and attempt to eat apples. As you eat more, you grow longer. If you hit yourself or a wall, you die.

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a program that I could use to play the game. The program I suppose would have to simulate up, down, left, and right inputs from the user. I feel like the logic would not be too tricky, but I have no idea where I would start with such a project.

So, I was wondering if anyone had any general suggestions that would help me get started with this project.

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: It seems obvious to me that this is a user looking to exploit the high score feature of an Internet game.  Maybe via programming, yes, but it still seems dishonest.

Comment: @Merlyn Haha I really have no desire to set the high score. I just thought it would be a fun project to do over my break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml). It is easy to use for such automation tasks.